# Changing an array's position, after using it inside OnCreate

Tags: android

Here is a quick show of the issue with my current code. It is created in Android Studio:

```
public class OptionActivity extends Activity {
Spinner spnr;

int songs[] = new int[] {R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound3,R.raw.sound4};

MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
int current_index = 0;
String[] mySelectSounds = {
        "Robot",
        "Manly man",
        "Woman",
        "Cat",
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_option);
    myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[0]);
    spnr = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mySelectSounds);

    spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
    spnr.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View    arg1,
                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                    int position = spnr.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected " + mySelectSounds[+position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    current_index = (current_index + position);
                    if (position == 3) {
                       myMediaPlayer.start();
//What to put here, to make it change the array number in myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[0]);?
                   }}
```

I have 4 arrays, which are supposed to be sounds. I want to be able to change which sound is used in the different positions of the dropdown menu/spinner through an array.

My issue is, when I create the myMediaPlayer in the OnCreate, I don't know how to change it. The int current_index is set to be the same as the position of the spinner, so I want to add that to the array's position, according to the menu number in my spinner. I have tried my own hand with it, but I'm fairly inexperienced with android studio, and the sample I have found, used the code

```
if (position == 3) {
    getResources().openRawResourceFd(songs[current_index]);
    myMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

which, according to the other questions asked here seems to work, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new MediaPlayer like this in your item click

`MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(OptionActivity.this, songs[current_index]);`

Comment: The current_index is 0, until it is added the position of my spinner, and the position of the spinner can only be used within its scope, at least in the current way I have written the code.

Comment: You have to recreate MediaPlayer everytime you want to play a sound, so if in the beggining it's 0, then it will only play item at 0. About your scope problem, just add a private int variable to the activity scope and you can use it everywhere within the class

Comment: Yeah, I have thought of that, but I need to use this code many times in my app, so I would preffer to find a way to use an array if possible, or even a simpler way if that is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 current_index = position;
                    if (current_index == 3) {
                       myMediaPlayer.start();
    myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[current_index]);
                   }}
```

Comment: The position int is only local to its scope. If I try to create the mediaplayer inside the OnItemSelected  it states that the method cannot be resolved

Comment: Then you can do that. First of all. Why are you adding current index to position? I think you should just say current_index = position?

Comment: About the current_index = positon, is just because that is the way I found the code on the internet. Guess there is no reason for it. And for my issue, it says the method cannot be resolved, same as before.